# Python Graph API request only retrieving 1 attachment from an email

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I'm using a python script to send an API request to get the attachments of an email. The email I'm using has 4 attachments (plus pictures in the signature in the email). The python request only retrieves 1 attachment along with the pics from the signature. When using Postman with the exact same information, it retrieves all attachments along with the pics.

Any ideas on how I can get the other attachments?

```
import requests
url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{users email}}/messages/{{messageID}}/attachments'
body = None
head = {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UFT-8", "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
response1 = requests.get(url, data=body, headers=head)
response = response1.text
```

Below shows the response from the python script, with only 7 items, and the Postman response with 10 items.

[image: Response from python script]
[image: Response from Postman]

Comment: Looks weird to me, what ever the client you use, if the call is perfect the data you get will be same in all cases. Try something like this `/attachments?$top=20` and see if it works.

Comment: Try what Shiva suggested above. But i suspect onething above. 7 are actual attachments, where in i think 3 are inline attachments. If its the case, the above Graph API call won't work.

Comment: In addition, you can try doing the listing of attachments (one level of nesting, but its not guranteed to get the inline attachments) GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/childFolders/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}

Answer (score 0):

Below code retrieves multiple attachments
(files being an array of attachment names)

```
def execute(accessToken, messageID, files, noAttachments): 
    import os
    from os import path
    import requests
    import base64
    import json
    
    if noAttachments == "False":
        url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{users email}}/messages/{{messageID}}/attachments'
        body = {}
        head = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
        responseCode = requests.request("GET", url, headers=head, data = body)
        response = responseCode.text
        test = json.loads(responseCode.text.encode('utf8'))
        x, contentBytes = response.split('"contentBytes":"',1)
        if len(files) == 1:
            imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(contentBytes))  
            filename = "C:/Temp/SAPCareAttachments/" + files[0]
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(imgdata)
        else:
            for file in test["value"]:
                imgdata = base64.b64decode(file["contentBytes"])
                if file["name"] in files:   
                    filename = "C:/Temp/" + file["name"]
                    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(imgdata)
print(responseCode)
```